# For SSH certificates, is it possible to know the embedded command at the server side?

Tags: openssh

we're using SSH certificates with a command inside:

`ssh-keygen -s ca-key -n user -O force-command="date" user-key.pub`

and they work as expected.

However, we also want to use `ForceCommand` option on the server (inside a *Match* section of *sshd_config*) to log the commands executed. As the command is embedded inside the certificate, the server passes an empty `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` to the wrapper. I couldn't find any additional environment variable for this case.

So, can the wrapper know the command embedded inside the certificate?

It would be useful too if the OpenSSH server could log it directly (aside from CA, certificate serial, etc), but couldn't find any option either.